# Scala: thread is unable to access variable outside of thread?

Tags: multithreading, scala, intellij-idea, concurrency

```
object Test extends App {
  val x = 0
  val threadHello = (1 to 5).map(_ => new Thread(() => {
    println("Hello")
    println(x) // this results in join never resolving "collecting data"
  }))
  threadHello.foreach(_.start())
  threadHello.foreach(_.join())
  println(x)
}
```

I'm still learning about concurrency in Scala but I'm having an issue where `thread.join()` never resolves and the program ends up running forever, UNLESS I comment out the `println(x)` statement.

Debugging reveals that the thread is never able to access the value of `x`, and I'm not sure why this is an issue.

[The problem highlighted when debugging in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWyuL.png)

Comment: 1. Don't use plain threads, rather use `Futures` or even higher level abstractions like actors, streams or `IO` - 2. I would guess the problem is the use of `App` switch to a plain `main` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code actually runs just fine for me, in Scala 2.13.

That said, I suspect your problem has to do with the initialization order of `val`s in `scala.App`. If so, you should be able to work around it by making `x` `lazy`, like so:

```
object Test extends App {
  lazy val x = 0
  val threadHello = (1 to 5).map(_ => new Thread(() => {
    println("Hello")
    println(x) // this results in join never resolving "collecting data"
  }))
  threadHello.foreach(_.start())
  threadHello.foreach(_.join())
  println(x)
}
```

Alternatively, just don't use `scala.App`:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val x = 0
    val threadHello = (1 to 5).map(_ => new Thread(() => {
      println("Hello")
      println(x) // this results in join never resolving "collecting data"
    }))
    threadHello.foreach(_.start())
    threadHello.foreach(_.join())
    println(x)
  }
}
```